# style hyperlinks in reportlab pdfs

Tags: python, reportlab, rst2pdf

I am using rst2pdf to generate a PDF. I am using links to sections and they appear as hyperlinks in the PDF. If I hover over the link I can see it says "Go to page XXX". Is there a way to insert that page number into the text, so that it can be seen on hardcopies?

Comment: You'd probably need to post-process the final pdf because only then could it be known what page something ended-up being on. A pdf viewer/reader can show this information because the contents and layout have been finalized by the time it's run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting using reportlab recently. Maybe you need to use the superscript tag?

```
p = Paragraph("<link href='http://someurl' color='blue'><u>Some text</u><super> [goto page xx]</super></link>", customstyle)
```

[What it may looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihZkd.jpg)